# HAProxy - Client Request Continuously Switching Servers

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, load-balancing, haproxy, heartbeat

I have configured a Software Load balancer with HAProxy.

- Here are the details :

  1. Load Balancer 1 (Master) - 10.0.0.2
  2. Load Balancer 2 (Slave) - 10.0.0.3
  3. Virtual IP that load balancer shared is - 10.0.0.1
  4. Web Server 1 with Apache : 10.0.0.4
  5. Web Server 2 with Apache : 10.0.0.5
  6. Web Server 3 with Apache : 10.0.0.6

I am able to access the website hosted on all Webservers through Virtual IP configured i.e 10.0.0.1

But, when i refresh the browser, the servers are getting switched from one to another.
Also, getting error "**503 Service Unavailable**", that too when refreshed, goes to another server.

Here is the HAProxy.conf file content [Master Load Balancer]:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1 local0  err
        ulimit-n 50000
        maxconn 24000
        nbproc 1
        stats socket /tmp/haproxysock
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        maxconn 5000
        contimeout 5000
        clitimeout 50000
        srvtimeout 50000

frontend UNBoxFrontEnd
        bind 10.0.0.1:80
        option http-server-close
        default_backend UNBoxBackEnd

backend UNBoxBackEnd
        option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
        hash-type consistent
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        server WebServer1 10.0.0.4:80 cookie Web1 check
        server WebServer2 10.0.0.5:80 cookie Web2 check
        server WebServer3 10.0.0.6:80 cookie Web3 check

listen web-cluster         10.0.0.1:80
        bind *:1936
        balance roundrobin
        stats enable
        stats scope UNBoxFrontEnd
        stats scope UNBoxBackEnd
        stats scope wordpress-backend
        stats uri /haproxy?stats
        stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
        stats auth test:test
        stats admin if TRUE
        errorfile    400    /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile    403    /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile    408    /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile    500    /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile    502    /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile    503    /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile    504    /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
```

Can you please help me out to make client always redirected to a single Webserver unless that goes down.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The 503 error sounds like you have a problem with one of your servers. I've posted an answer to the load balancer issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `balance roundrobin` line in HAProxy.cfg. This tells HAProxy to round-robin between all available nodes. Change it to something else (as detailed in the [haproxy documentation](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#balance)) and you should get the behaviour you want.

For posterity, the (IMO) most popular options to the 'balance' directive are:

- `roundrobin` - classic round-robin balancing.
- `static-rr` - a variant which allows for more servers by disabling some functionality.
- `leastconn` - balance to the server with least connections first.
- `source` - hash the source IP address and balance based on that.
- `uri` - hash some or all of the URI and balance based on that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback shearn89!  I tried with different balance algorithms still getting the similar response.

Comment: The blurb for the `source` algorithm would imply that it's a best attempt at sticky sessions. If your problem is the 503 error still then I'm not sure that's a load balancing issue, but a problem with the Apache config on that node. Does it happen on all nodes or just one? Do all the nodes work when you navigate to them directly?

Comment: Thanks again for your valuable feedback! 
I think 503 error resolved on deleting listener server on "listen web-cluster"
Yes, it works correctly when i directly access nodes.
Only thing is, when i access 10.0.0.1, lets say i got navigated to 10.0.0.4 and when i refresh it goes to 10.0.0.5 or 10.0.0.6 and vice-a-versa.
how can i make it consistent

Comment: I'm not sure - I'd expect `balance source` to do that, as it should hash your source IP and then effectively stick you to one server. Does this help? http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/03/29/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! 
it worked.. many thanks.. :) you saved my day!